# Print Output Into Console or File as per parameter in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

### Option 1:Write File only

```
LOG_FILE=/tmp/1.txt
su - oracle <<EOF >> $LOG_FILE
whoami
echo "Heloo"
EOF
```

### Option 2:print on console as well as Write File

```
LOG_FILE=/tmp/1.txt
su - oracle <<EOF | tee -a $LOG_FILE
whoami
echo "Heloo"
EOF
```

Trying a parameter if i will pass 1 means option1 ,if 2 option2.its working if same code repeating 2 times using if option 1 else option 2,want to minimize the code passing a variable but its not working.

```
LOG_FILE=/tmp/1.txt
if [ ${1} -eq 1 ] 
then
x=">> $LOG_FILE"
else
x="| tee -a $LOG_FILE"
fi
su - oracle <<EOF $x
whoami
echo "Heloo"
EOF
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very almost there you can use eval to execute the command

you can just create this  **su - oracle** command as variable as and concatenate with variable x  as shown

```
LOG_FILE=/tmp/1.txt
if [ ${1} -eq 1 ] 
then
x=">> $LOG_FILE"
else
x="| tee -a $LOG_FILE"
fi
y="su - oracle <<EOF $x"
```

then you can use eval to execute complete expression

```
   eval $y
```

rest will remain same.

Complete code.

```
LOG_FILE=/tmp/1.txt
if [ ${1} -eq 1 ] 
then
x=">> $LOG_FILE"
else
x="| tee -a $LOG_FILE"
fi
y="su - oracle <<EOF $x"
z="EOF"
eval $y
whoami
echo "Heloo"
eval $z
exit 0
```

If above is not working you can try by creating different function for both scenarios

```
LOG_FILE="p.txt"
logFile()
{
su -oracle <<EOF >> "${LOG_FILE}"
whoami
echo "HEllo"
EOF
}
logPrint()
{
su -oracle <<EOF | tee -a "${LOG_FILE}"
whoami
echo "HEllo"
EOF
}
if [ ${1} -eq 1 ] 
then
    logFile
elif [ ${1} -eq 2 ]
     logPrint
 fi
```

Comment: code is not working.getting error:line 9: warning: here-document at line 9 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF') and line 12: EOF: command not found